# Is the cross product of two vectors always perpendicular to both?

Tags: vectors

Does the cross product of two vectors result in a vector perpendicular to both of the vectors *or* does the cross product of **only two perpendicular** vectors result in a vector perpendicular to both of the vectors?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product Did you even read the second line here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross product of two vectors, be there any angle between them, is perpendicular to the two vectors. It is, more precisely, perpendicular to the *plane* containing the two vectors. The direction is determined by the *right hand thumb rule/corkscrew rule*. The magnitude of the vector is given by $|{\bf A} \times {\bf B}| = |{\bf A}| |{\bf B}| \sin\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the cross product of two vectors always perpendicular to both?

No. The cross product is the zero vector if one or both of the vectors is the zero vector, or if the two vectors are parallel or anti-parallel to one another. The angle between the zero vector and some other vector is indeterminate. What you can say is that

- $(\vec A \times \vec B) \cdot \vec A = (\vec A \times \vec B) \cdot \vec B = 0$ for all vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$, and
- Given two vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ such that $||\vec A \times \vec B|| > 0$, then $\vec A \times \vec B$ is orthogonal to both $\vec A$ and $\vec B$.